# Git: How does git decide which files to delete during checkouts?

Tags: git, git-checkout

One thing about Git that I'm trying to understand is how it deals with files which aren't tracked, or which *weren't* tracked but now are committed.

Here's an example:

```
echo "one" > one.txt
git add one.txt
git commit -m "#1"
```

So, "one.txt" is in the first commit. Now, I'll create two more files, but only add *one* of them (and I'll tag this next commit as "#2" so that we can return to it):

```
echo "two" > two.txt
echo "three" > three.txt
git add two.txt
git commit -m "#2"
git tag "#2"
```

So, "two.txt" is in the 2nd commit, and "three.txt" is just this extra file, hanging around. Then, I checkout HEAD~ and, sure enough, Git removes the file "two.txt", because that didn't exist back then...

```
git checkout HEAD~
ls
___ one.txt three.txt
```

Okay.. back to the end of the branch, and only *add* the third file. So, we're only *tracking* it. *Then* let's step backward one commit...

```
git checkout "#2"
git add three.txt
git checkout HEAD~
ls
___ one.txt three.txt
```

Ummm... okay... so just *tracking* a file isn't enough to have Git manage whether it's there or not. So, we go to the end of the branch, again, and commit, then back up (twice, this time, to get back to commit #1) and what do we see?

```
git checkout "#2"
git commit -m "#3"
git checkout HEAD~~
ls
___ one.txt
```

This time, Git has deleted the file "three.txt". So, my question is: Can someone describe just *how* Git decided to do that? It doesn't seem to be simply whether a filename appears in *any* tree object in the respository, because I can create a *new* three.txt (a filename which is being *tracked* and has a *committed* version in the respository, and then do more checkouts, and Git leaves it alone, again, like before.

Can someone explain how Git decides what is okay to **delete** when doing checkouts?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than come up with my own explanation, I'll direct you to the excellent [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository), which is free :). That link is to the relevant section, and explains very well the various states.

Your explanation covers the way Git will care about files pretty comprehensively. Forgetting about resets for a minute, Git will apply changes to the working directory to take it from state X to state Y (using the recorded changesets). If you have a file which you haven't committed, or have altered since it was last committed, Git sees this as a later change, so won't undo work which isn't committed, even if the file didn't exist in the previous commit.

This is a pretty sane strategy because it lessens the risk of losing uncommitted work.

If you're wanting to remove changes from your working directory and go back to the clean state (of the HEAD commit) you can do `git checkout -- .` or replace `.` with the file/directory of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

One key to understanding this is that `git add` merely puts the file into the index; that doing a `git checkout` compares the trees for the "from" and "to" *commits* (if path `P` exists in "from" but not in "to", path `P` is desired-to-be-removed); and that `checkout` writes *through* the index into the working directory (clobbering index-only changes).  The other is the general principle of "don't overwrite-or-remove anything that is not committed".

Let's take the particular case in question.  You were "on" commit #2 with an untracked file `three.txt`.  You then `git add three.txt`.  It's now in the index, but not committed, so it is (still) not in the tree for the current (`HEAD`) commit, which is the one tagged `#2`.

Now you ask git to check out commit "#1".  Compare the trees: `HEAD` resolves "#2", which has files `one.txt` and `two.txt`.  `HEAD~` resolves to "#1", which has `one.txt` but not `two.txt`.  The recipe for converting the working tree is therefore "remove `two.txt`, and if `one.txt` differs, replace it."  (And, removal entails removing the index entry as well as the work-tree copy, while replacing entails writing through the index.)

The "verify no work will be clobbered" step then has to check:

- What happens to the index versions of `two.txt` and maybe `one.txt`?
- What happens to the work-tree versions of same?

While `three.txt` is in the index now, there is no need to remove it or change the index version, so it simply remains in the index now as "ready to be added to a new commit".

Now (with `HEAD` pointing to #1) you ask to `git checkout #2`.  Git has to repeat the above, but this time the tree comparison result is "add `two.txt`, and maybe replace `one.txt`".  The verify-no-clobbering step checks that these are OK (they are) and git does the checkout.  The index entry for `three.txt` *still* remains as "ready to be added to a new commit".

Once you do the `git commit -m '#3'`, git writes the index into a tree (this is relatively easy, much easier than scanning the work directory directly; in effect, the index is a fancied up, intermediate form kind of halfway between a git repo tree entry and a working tree) and writes a new commit with that as its tree.

The last `git checkout`, then, is done while `HEAD` resolves to commit #3, and moves from there to commit #1.  Comparing the trees, the change from #3 to #1 is "delete `two.txt`, delete `three.txt`, maybe replace `one.txt`".  The checkout has to verify that no work will be clobbered (it won't), and then it does that.

Note that if you shuffle things around "behind git's back", by changing the commit to which `HEAD` points without altering the index (`git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/differentbranch` or `git update-ref HEAD HEAD~` for instance), you can get some interesting effects.  Here's what I did for an example:

```
$ git commit -m '#3'
[detached HEAD e3465c4] #3
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 three.txt
$ git tag #3  # since we're "detached", let's save #3
$ git status
$ git status
HEAD detached at #3
$ git update-ref HEAD '#2'
$ git status
HEAD detached from #3
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   three.txt

$ git update-ref HEAD HEAD^
$ git status
HEAD detached from #3
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   three.txt
    new file:   two.txt
```

The `update-ref` operation does not touch the index, but it does change the commit (and hence the tree) to which `HEAD` points.  Thus, comparing index vs current-commit-tree gives different results.